# Write a Class which returns different values when called as list(c) and dict(c)

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a custom class which returns a different value when called as `list(c)` or `dict(c)`. However, it is my impression that both `list(c)` and `dict(c)` use `c.__iter__()` under the hood? If that is the case, how can I get different behaviour calling `list(c)` and `dict(c)`? I know that it is possible because Python dictionaries and pandas DataFrames have different hevariours.

For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._keys = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'e']
        self._data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    def __iter__(self):
        for key, value in zip(self._keys, self._data):
            yield key, value
```

Calling `dict(c)` I get what I want:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> dict(f)
{'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'd': 40, 'e': 50}
```

However, I can't get `list(c)` to print out a list of keys (or values), but instead get both:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> list(f)
[('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('d', 30), ('d', 40), ('e', 50)]
```

The equivalent code for a dictionary is much cleaner:

```
>>> f = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40, 'e': 50}
>>> dict(f)
{'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40, 'e': 50}
>>> list(f)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: This is because you yield tuples (key,value forms a tuple and the python list function just stores them all in a list).

Comment: I know, but if I yield one value at a time, `dict(c)` does not work property.

Comment: `list` and `dict` call the same magic methods; there is no way to make a class return something different depending on what called it. I'd suggest that you make `keys()` and `values()` methods to return lists.

Comment: You need `f` to be a `Mapping` type in order to get that sort of behavior.  Inheriting from `collections.Mapping` _might_ be helpful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously the `__iter__` must only return the *keys*, otherwise `list(f)` wouldn't work.

The Python documentation says the following of the [`dict` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping):

> If a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping object.

Now, the question is what is a "mapping" enough for the `dict` constructor? `DataFrame` doesn't inherit from any mapping class, neither is it registered against an abstract base class. It turns out we only need to support the `keys` method: If the object passed to `dict` constructor has a method called `keys`, this is called to provide an iterable of the keys [[CPython source]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce552e2d5c4ff90218fb41847e8ffb1fd3ba3b2d/Objects/dictobject.c). For each key, the value is fetched by indexing.

I.e. the `dict` constructor does the logical equivalent of the following:

```
if hasattr(source, 'keys'):
    for k in source.keys():
        self[k] = source[k]
else:
    self.update(iter(source))
```

Using this we get

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._keys = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'e']
        self._data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.keys)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        idx = self._keys.index(key)
        return self._data[idx]

    def keys(self):
        return self._keys
```

Testing:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> list(f)
['a', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'e']

>>> dict(f)
{'d': 30, 'e': 50, 'a': 10, 'b': 20}
```

(As you can see from the code above, there is no need to actually inherit from anything)

However, it is not guaranteed that *all* mapping constructors behave in the same way - some other might call `items` - thus the most compatible way would be to implement all of the methods required by [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) and inherit from it. I.e. it would be enough to do

```
class Foo(collections.abc.Mapping):
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        idx = self._keys.index(key)
        return self._data[idx]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._keys)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._keys)
```

Comment: def __iter__(self):
        return iter(keys)
`self.keys` probably

Answer (score 2):

@mgilson's comment is correct, this can be accomplished by inheriting from the `collections.abc.Mapping` class:

```
class Foo(collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __init__(self):
        self._keys = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'e']
        self._data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self._keys:
            yield key

    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self._data[self._keys.index(value)]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._keys)
```

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> list(f)
['a', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'e']

>>> dict(f)
{'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'd': 30, 'e': 50}
```